# The best ocaml way to verify the preorder list could be obtained from a BST

Tags: ocaml

Given a list of numbers, I need to verify this list is a valid preorder of any existing BST. For example, 1,2,3 is one valid preorder list, however, 3 4 2 is not valid one.

In Java, I will try to implement a function signature like this 
`bool isvalid(int[] list, int start_index, int[] cur_index)`
Then logic would be like check left tree is valid and then check right subtree is valid or not.
And the `cur_index` will store the information about how many list elements has been consumed by the left tree, so I could check right subtree from index cur_index[0] + 1.

However, In Ocaml, I was told it is not recommended to introduce this "call by reference" parameter in function call. So what is the best way to attack this kind of problem?

Thank you.

Comment: In general, try to post and show what code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

In general the way to maintain a state throughout a pure functional computation is to pass the state as a parameter, and have each function return a possibly updated state. You can do this, but it will involve a quite lot of array copying.

However, it seems to me you'd like to process your list in a streaming fashion; i.e., you'd like to traverse it just once. So a subtree size doesn't seem particularly useful. It just tells you how much of the list to skip; i.e., to traverse a second time.

It seems much more useful just to return the unprocessed remainder of the list, as if this were a parsing problem. (Not to give too much away I hope.)